# Dictionary of dictionaries in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, nested

I'd like to build a dictionary of dictionaries. In Swift how do I declare a dictionary with a key of a String and the value of a dictionary of this same type? I need to be able to have potentially infinite nests. (Kind of like building a tree using nodes. Except it's not a tree, it's a dictionary.)

I tried using AnyObject, but get a conversion error:

```
var node1: Dictionary<String, AnyObject?> = ["foo" : nil]
var node2: Dictionary<String, AnyObject?> = ["bar" : node1] // ERROR: Cannot convert value of type 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject?>' (aka 'Dictionary<String, Optional<AnyObject>>') to expected dictionary value type 'Optional<AnyObject>'
```

Is there a type-safe way of doing this (i.e., not using AnyObject?)

Comment: After how many dictionaries does it end? Or is it dictionaries all the way down?

Comment: yes, it's infinite.

Comment: Surly having an infinite nest of dictionaries would mean you never actually store any data? As you would have a String for the key and then another dictionary as the value. You would never store anything other than keys. I think maybe another data structure would be better suited. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just use `AnyObject` as the stored type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve something like this with a nice API and type safety in swift by using a struct and an enumeration.

```
enum RecursiveDictValue<KeyType: Hashable, ValueType> {
    case Value(ValueType)
    case Dict(RecursiveDict<KeyType, ValueType>)
}

struct RecursiveDict<KeyType: Hashable, ValueType> {
    typealias OwnType = RecursiveDict<KeyType, ValueType>

    private var dict: [KeyType: RecursiveDictValue<KeyType, ValueType>]

    init() {
        dict = [:]
    }

    init(dict: [KeyType: RecursiveDictValue<KeyType, ValueType>]) {
        self.dict = dict
    }

    // this ensures that we can safely chain subscripts
    subscript(key: KeyType) -> OwnType {
        get {
            switch dict[key] {
            case let .Dict(dict)?:
                return dict
            default:
                return RecursiveDict<KeyType, ValueType>()
            }
        }

        set(newValue) {
            dict[key] = .Dict(newValue)
        }
    }

    subscript(key: KeyType) -> ValueType? {
        get {
            switch dict[key] {
            case let .Value(value)?:
                return value
            default:
                return nil
            }
        }

        set(newValue) {
            if let newValue = newValue {
                dict[key] = RecursiveDictValue<KeyType, ValueType>.Value(newValue)
            } else {
                dict[key] = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works quite nicely (note that you need to help swift with the types though):

```
var dict = RecursiveDict<String, Int>(dict: ["value":.Value(1),
                                             "dict":.Dict(RecursiveDict<String, Int>(dict: ["nestedValue": .Value(2)]))])

if let value: Int = dict["value"] {
    print(value) // prints 1
}

if let value: Int = dict["dict"]["nestedValue"] {
    print(value) // prints 2
}
```

It also fails as intended when you do stuff that can't work.

```
if let value: Int = dict["dict"] {
    print(value) // is not executed
}

if let value: Int = dict["dict"]["nestedDict"]["nestedValue"] {
    print(value) // is not executed
}
```

And you can even set values in nested dictionaries that haven't been created yet!:

```
dict["dict"]["nestedDict2"]["nestedValue"] = 3


if let value: Int = dict["dict"]["nestedDict2"]["nestedValue"] {
    print(value) // prints 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was working with firebase, and i needed to achieve an structure similar to this:

```
["llave3": ["hola": "", "dos": ""], "llave1": ["hola": "", "dos": ""],     "llave2": ["hola": "", "dos": ""]]
```

This is a nested dictionary, or a dictionary of dictionaries. I achieve this by simply doing this:

```
 var array = ["llave1", "llave2","llave3"]
 var dictOfDictionarys =  [String : [String : String]] ()

 for items in array {
      dictOfDictionarys[items] = ["hola":"","dos":""]
 }
```

Comment: This only goes to a depth of one, OP needs one that goes down forever

Answer (score 0):

Very less info.. and you mean infinite nested dictionaries? I dont think so..

```
    func returnDict() -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        return ["Got You" : returnDict()]
    }


var x : Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["GotYou" : returnDict()]
```

Just saying, nothing better can happen to this other than a crash

this is a case of infinite recursion. When you have infinite dictionaries, it doesnt mean that it is going to run forever. It means that it is going to run till your device runs out of memory. A call to function returnDict, calls returnDict, which again calls returnDict and so on.

A recursion is basically adding a method onto the stack of pre-existing stack of methods in memory.. this can happen until the stack overflows. Hence, stackOverFlow

```
let node1: Dictionary<String, AnyObject!> = ["foo" : nil]
var node2 = ["bar" : node1]
```

Playground approves of it

[image]

Comment: why would you need infinite nests? And how would it help you?

Comment: Cause I only know at runtime how deep it needs to be.

Comment: This is never going to stop because you didnt mention any return at all.

Comment: if you had posted that earlier, you wouldn't have gotten so many downvotes

Comment: My goal is not to get a stack overflow, as your code produces. It's to build a data structure. Just like if I wanted to build a tree I would use the same technique.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113332/discussion-between-akshansh-thakur-and-daniel).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that like in Objective-C values in the `Dictionary` type must be non-optional.

It's not very useful anyway because in Swift assigning a `nil` value to a key removes the key.

```
var node1: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["foo" : "Hello"]
var node2: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["bar" : node1]
```